How to use @viewChildren by reference in Angular?
I have a set of inputs like this.
<input #lookup1 (click)="onClick($event, 1)">
<input #lookup2 (click)="onClick($event, 2)">

In the component, I reference them like this.
@ViewChild("lookup1") input1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("lookup2") input2: ElementRef;

The issue is that when reacting to the changes, I have to use the following passage.
onClick(data: any, index: number) {
  ...
  if (index === 1)
    this.selector1.nativeElement.value = data.name;
  if (index === 2)
    this.selector2.nativeElement.value = data.name;
}

I'd like to use @ViewChildren and work with an array so the index will be a gain not a pain. However, I can't seen to find any example of how to do that (except for a lot of those that target a child component of a certain type). In my case, I need to select the children by markup, not component type (hence, the references only).
I've tried this. No good. Array is empty.
@ViewChildren("div") selectors = QueryList<ElementRef>;

I also tried different variations of creating an array and putting the input1, input2 etc. into it. Failure due to the this.input1 not being created at the moment of declaring the array.
How should I approach it?
edit
I tried to use the below (inspired by this fiddle). However, it seems that my selectors can't see toArray() and I get error telling me that it doesn't have that method. (It seems to work in the console of the browser when I console-log-out it. There's also _results fired that I can't access in the source code.)
this.selectors.toArray()
  .find(a => a.nativeElement.value === ...);

I tried the hint of naming the elements with the same name, as suggested in the comments. It seems to work on my machine (still not getting the arrayification to work, though). But it seems to break in the fiddle above, producing error that no two elements can have the same reference.
I'm starting to get rather confused by those different behaviors...

Why don't you go with @ViewChildren("lookup") with the #lookup reference on each element ?

@MatthieuRiegler Please view the edit in the question.

Could you not just bind to an <input [(ngModel)]="lookup1" /> and <input [(ngModel)]="lookup2" />?

Are you on v17 ? Can you use the new signal based viewChildren() ?

@GetOffMyLawn Excellent! Your suggestion in combination with the reference suggested by Mattieu did the trick. (I still can't understand why it works with the repeated use of #lookup for multiple DIVs (when the linked StackBlitz complains). But that's a "it works - but why" kind of problem.   :)

@MatthieuRiegler Regrettably, I can't upgrade from v16 because we're relying on Azure for user/security management. And the MSAL package for facilitating the security won't work with Angular 17. Microsoft dropped the ball there and it's embarrassing to see. (They promised to have a fix for it by the end of March but it didn't happen.) I'll have to wait.   :(
